# How to create bitnami redis-cluster ACL user and persist entry on redis.conf?

Tags: redis, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, redis-cluster, configmap

I am using helm chart-"redis-cluster-4.4.0", have successfully deployed 6 pods (3 master + 3 slave). Now I am trying to create ACL user. Have used below command from redis-client to create ACL user-

to connect to redis-server through client :

```
redis-cli -h localhost -c 
AUTH password
```

Then have created redis ACL user:

```
ACL SETUSER user1 on >password123 +@all ~*
ACL LIST
```

able to see newly created ACL user. and able to switch between user as well.

Problem is when I am disconnecting the redis-client session and then reconnecting, I found newly created ACL user entry gone.

To persist ACL entry to redis.conf have tried config rewrite command but it is giving me error that redis server is running without redis.conf (which populated through configmap).

Please let me know, how I can persist ACL entry to redis.conf file in this case?

Also let me know, how can I run redis-server by passing external redis.conf in bitnami redis-cluster helm chart?

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0):

To add extra configuration to the Redis configuration you can use the `configmap` parameter, providing the name of an already existing configmap containing the configuration. Check https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/04a144858cd35140aeb75a715dc1281887819055/bitnami/redis-cluster/values.yaml#L159.

> Problem is when I am disconnecting the redis-client session and then reconnecting, I found newly created ACL user entry gone.

About this, I would say it is because you are reconnecting to a different node than the one you connected the first time. The redis.conf is not shared once Redis is installed so probably the proper approach to do this will be to create the ACL user before deploying the Redis cluster.
Could you try creating the users in the configuration file instead of after the deployment? You can check this section https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/04a144858cd35140aeb75a715dc1281887819055/bitnami/redis-cluster/templates/configmap.yaml#L661